# Android - Passing a lot of paremeters to an ASyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

One of the REST APIs my app calls, requires 7 parameters. On top of that, I need to handle the adapter and the SwipeRefreshLayout when it's done. It means that I need to pass 9 parameters to the ASyncTask in order for it to process correctly.

Moreover, I have to call an ASyncTask to do something and only then I can call the ASyncTask that actually calls the REST API so that means I need to pass them all, also to the first one, just so it will be able to call the next one.

Is this the right approach? Sending 9 parameters? Or is there a better, more efficient, cleaner way to do it?

Comment: are all 7 parameters specific to the context and cannot be obtained in the asynctask directly? (more clearly, what are these parameters? can they be formed into a list of namevaluepair beforehanding them to the asynctask?)

Comment: 2 parameters are adapter and swipeLayout (so it's a "no" to your other question) + 3 parameters that are coming from the user. 2 parameters will come from the middle ASyncTask. 2 values I can obtain in the ASynkTask itself, so it means 5 params from A->B and 7 params from B->C.